# Adding Sequences proof

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, proof-verification

1. Prove that if $a,b : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R} $ are sequences with $\lim_{n \to \infty}{a_n} = L$  and $\lim_{n \to \infty}{b_n} = M$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty}{a_n+b_n} = L + M$
2. Prove that if $\lim_{n \to \infty}{a_n} = L$ and $f$ is continuous then $\lim_{n \to \infty}{f{(a_n)}} =f{(L)}$
3. Prove that if $m$ is a fixed integer, like $17, or -101$, and $\lim_{n \to \infty}{a_n} = L$ then also $\lim_{n \to \infty}{a_n+a_m}=L$

My thoughts, part one is just using the definition of convergence for a limit, and I choose $\epsilon = \epsilon / 2 $ for each sequence. Part two is where I start to get tripped up, Can I use the contraction principle here, or is that incorrect.

Part three makes sense that if a sequence converges, it does not matter how many numbers out you go in the sequence, because there is an upper bound for the sequence. I just don't know how to put this in words to make it sound correct.

Comment: For part 3, wouldn't the limit be $L+a_m$?

Answer (score 0):

For part 2,
you want to show that
$|f(a_n)-f(L)|$
gets as small as you want.

Since $f$ is continuous,
as $x \to L$,
$f(x) \to f(L)$.
Since $a_n \to L$,
see how you can go from
$a_n \to L$
to $x \to L$.